# How to assert sendkeys in protractor using chai?

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, bdd, chai

While writing steps for scenarios, using sendkeys() of the protractor I had a confusion in handling assertion for input text box. how to handle it or **do I need of any assert to sendkeys**?

Comment: `sendKeys()` has no return value, so not make sense to do assertion on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about asserting that what was entered in the textbox is what you expect to be there you have to use the `value` attribute.

```
const ele = element(by.css('.some-css'));
await ele.sendKeys('Test');

const inputValue = await ele.getAttribute('value');
expect(inputValue).toEqual('Test');
```

I use this approach for checking data persistence after a form has been saved.